# CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect with a transform

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform, cgpath

Experimenting with the use of the `CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect` function in Swift, I am having this issue:

This code works as I expect, I get a path and can make use of it:

```
CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord,
                width: theWidth, height: theHeight), nil)
```

But this one does not work:

```
var affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.0)

CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord,
                width: theWidth, height: theHeight), &affineTransform)
```

It seems like I get no path at all (or an empty one). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code

```
var affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.0)

let path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord,
                width: theWidth, height: theHeight), &affineTransform)
```

*is correct* and does work. Note however, that you create a rotation
with an angle of 1.0 * 180/π ≈ 57  degrees around the view's origin
(which is the top-left corner by default).
This probably moves the ellipse out of the visible bounds of the view.

The equivalent of passing a `nil` transform would be a rotation
about a zero angle

```
var affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)
```

and if your intention was to rotate about one degree, then use

```
var affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(1.0 * M_PI/180.0))
```

If your intention is to rotate the ellipse around its center,
then you have to combine the rotation with a translation which
makes the center of the ellipse the origin of the coordinate system:

```
var affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xCoord + theWidth/2.0, yCoord + theHeight/2.0)
affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(affineTransform, angle)
let path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(x: -theWidth/2.0, y: -theHeight/2.0,
    width: theWidth, height: theHeight), &affineTransform)
```

Comment: You are right that was the problem (where I didn't expect it) simpler than I thougt. I am just not rotating around the right point.
I want my rotation around the center of the ellipse.

Comment: @Michel: You probably figured it out by now. If not: see updated answer.

Comment: Yes thanks, indeed I used that same method, plus a translation at the end, opposite of the first one, to recover my original position. But seeing your last instruction it seems you're doing the same a slightly different way.
I did not change my last instruction, only worked on affineTransform.